# What could be my clan's sutra?

Tags: yajur-veda, gotra

I belong to Gaargya gotra and follow the Yajurveda (Madhyanddinya). Our family does not remember the "sutra" of the Yajurveda that our clan was supposed to follow.

I was wondering if Yajurvedis of Gaargya gotra follow one particular sutra? Or could I just assume it to be Apastambha?

According to this: https://www.vedicjyotishkrti.in/details-of-garg-gotra/ its Katyayana.

Comment: Yes Katyayana/Paraskara is the kalpa sutra book for Shukla Yajurveda both Kanva and Madhyandina Shakhas. Apastamba on the other hand is for Krishna Yajurveda. So yes since you belong to the madhyandina shakha, your Sutra will be Katyayana/Paraskara

Comment: Can you please add the references and the answer, I will accept the answer